# Force parameter evaluation for anonymous function

Tags: c#

I wonder if there's easy way to force parameter evaluation for anonymous function? It is significant

for multithread programming. 
For example when i wrote

```
        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
        }
```

Most people would get "5" five times. In fact the code snip is more likely expected to ouput 0 to 5.

One quick solution is following:

```
        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        {
            var local = i;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine(local));
        }
```

I think life is better if following method existed to evaluate all parameters for anonymous function and return one as same logic as the origin:

```
    Action EvaluateParameters(Action action)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How would they get 5, 5 times?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Try it, its true. Eric Lippert's written about that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: That is why Java force you to declare those variables as 'final'.

Comment: It's not necessarily 5 times 5. You don't know when it's to be executed, since this is all handled by the scheduler, and you have little influence on this. The first one can be anything between 0 and 5, the second one can between 1 and 5, and so on. 5 times 5 usually is the case, since the current thread probably finishes the loop before the new tasks are started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if such a method is even (reasonably) possible without compiler or framework support. In the end the compiler does generate code to hoist the variable, not it's value at the time you create the delegate, which leads to that behavior.

Basically, you would have to "execute" the delegate inside "EvaluteParameters" to get it working. Or maybe fiddling with Expressions could somehow do that.

BTW, this is only an issue if the delegate is created *inside* the loop but invoked *outside* (after) it.

Oh, and ReSharper does have a warning for that (even though it is sometimes "wrong" or overly pedantic).

Anyway, Jon Skeet does mention in his book (C# in Depth), that there is indeed some confusion about this in the community and that Microsoft is considering maybe changing the behavior in a future version (hopefully I got that somewhat right from memory). Which might not even be possible without breaking existing code that does depend on the current behavior (or works accidentally because of it).

Comment: Thank you. I also think the only way to realize it is to go through the expression(anonymous function) and evaluate parameters properly.